# Universal App (wp8.1) app manifest SMinVersion specified does not recognize XML fields with namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compilation, win-universal-app

When creating app package for wp 8.1 universal, i'm getting this error:

> App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per
>   schema: Line 31, Column 15, Note: The schema for OSMinVersion
>   specified does not recognize XML fields with namespace

Based on this topic
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f95daa41-c7af-406b-a7d9-46d53e990bd4/create-app-package-error?forum=wpdevelop

It seems that a repair or reinstall could do the trick. 
So far i tried a repair but it did not worked out for me, a reinstall looks my last option in line.

However, i don't think this is the solution to my problem either...

When creating a brand new project out of vs 2013 i'm also getting the error.
Am i'm missing something out here?